# What's the difference between installing Ubuntu and then installing desktop KDE on it or installing direct kubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde-plasma, xfce

What's the difference between

1.installing Ubuntu and changing its desktop to KDE or direct installing kubuntu

2.installing Ubuntu and changing its desktop to XFCE or direct installing xubuntu

3.installing Ubuntu and changing its desktop to LXDE or direct installing lubuntu

4.installing Ubuntu and changing its desktop to mate or direct installing Ubuntu mate

5.installing Ubuntu and changing its desktop to gnome or direct installing  gubuntu

Please help... I am confused..

Comment: Downvoted because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all Ubuntu-based distros with different tweaks. Each distro runs on the same Linux kernel, so they're the really same for most intents and purposes. The obvious difference, as you have stated, is the desktop manager installed on each one, so a different look and feel. However, each of them also comes with different packages pre-installed. Each distro may ship with different video viewers, photo viewers, email clients, photo editors, and so on.

Each one will also consume different amounts of RAM, CPU, and power.

For more information, this post has very good tables and graphs to compare the distros: http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.com/2014/11/ubuntu-1410-vs-kubuntu-1410-vs-xubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

This question should probably be asked on https://askubuntu.com/ but i'll answer it anyway. When installing Ubuntu you are greeted with a unity desktop meaning that all the unity package dependencies have been installed. If you were to install KDE on ubuntu (which is totally fine) you would still be left with unity desktop installed on your system. This is not ideal for computers with low storage or resources which is why different flavours of ubuntu have been released, aka kubuntu, ubuntu MATE. When installed these operating systems will only include the packages needed to run their own desktop (among other things like `apt`)